# How can I use Get-S3Object to change the cache headers on my bucket objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have already used this command so I think I am half way there:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName abilitest1 | % { Remove-S3Object -BucketName abilitest1 -Key $_.Key -Force:$true }
```

Using something similar is there a way I could change my cache-headers to for example 1 hour? Note I am looking for an AWS PowerShell solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The REST API to change metadata is PUT Copy (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html)

Using powershell, you can use `Write-S3Object` when uploading new objects (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html) or `Copy-S3Object` to change existing objects.